# How do I get filters to work on nested SVGs?

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to get a hover effect for some svgs. The code I'm working on is basically icons contained in an svg so they're all positioned on top of a background (it looks like a map - I want individual icons on the map to highlight on hover).

The problem is filters don't seem to have any effect on nested svg elements. I've tried putting the filter directly in the nested element and it doesn't change anything.

Here's a simple example of the code that I would like to work.

```css
.icon:hover{
        filter: sepia(100%);
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <svg x="10" class="icon">
        <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="fill: #0000ff"/>
      </svg>
      <svg x="200">
        <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="fill: #0000ff"/>
      </svg>

    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does seem to work on the snippet, doesn't it?

Comment: It's supposed to go sepia when you hover over it. I changed the boxes to be the same color if that made it unclear. Does it get sepia when you hover over the left box?

Comment: The left one with the class does becomes darker. I guess if you put an image it will do the job.

Comment: There is no change for me using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: It looks like it works in Firefox and not Chrome. I guess this is an issue with css-filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use svg filters. The `sepiatone` filter is from https://gist.github.com/jorgeatgu/5b338cc1a4e0df901348

```css
svg{border:1px solid}

.icon:hover{
    filter: url(#sepiatone);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<filter id="sepiatone">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".343 .669 .119 0 0 .249 .626 .130 0 0 .172 .334 .111 0 0 .000 .000 .000 1 0"/>
</filter>
</defs>
      <svg x="10" class="icon">
        <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="fill: #0000ff"/>
      </svg>
      <svg x="200">
        <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="fill: #0000ff"/>
      </svg>
    </svg>
```

Comment: It looks like the code I posted works in firefox but not chrome. This code works in both.